# Find all elements with a specific attribute that has a name starting with some string

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Say I have elements like these:

```
<h1 data-myapp-title>Title</h1>
<p data-myapp-description>Description</p>
```

How can I filter them by attribute name that is "data-myapp-*" with jQuery?

Comment: You mean like `$('[data-myapp-title],[data-myapp-description]')` or more flexibility than specifying fixed attribute names?

Comment: I'd like to use regular expressions if possible so the end can be any string, not from some set.

Comment: What do you mean use regular expressions? As an attribute selector?

Comment: I'm not sure I can get a list of the applied attributes. Looking in to it now however. *edit* nevermind, found out how. Writing it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not bullet-proof, but this should get you close. I made it in to a selector to make it a bit easier, but this is the general premise:

- Returns any elements that have an attribute that matches the selector
- Allows you to specify wildcard or regex pattern. (Simple testing worked, but probably should do a lot more)

```
(function($){
    $.expr[':']['attr'] = function(obj,index,meta,stack){
        var re = new RegExp(meta[3]), m = false;
        for (var a = 0; a < obj.attributes.length; a++){
            m |= re.test(obj.attributes[a].name);
        }
        return m;
    };
})(jQuery);

$(':attr(data-myapp-*)').css('color','#f0f');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/pkqgH/)

Comment: I cannot express this enough--not tested thoroughly or rigorously. I would run this through the ringer if it's getting anything close to semi-production. Also, I can't imagine iterating over attributes for every element and applying a test is efficient, so I'm sure someone else with editing power can add their $0.02 worth of optimizations.

Comment: I am going to use it for preprocessing needs on server side with NodeJS so performance is not so important for me. Thanks for the solution!